# What are the requirements for an entity to be granted observer status for the UN General Assembly?

Tags: united-nations

I stumbled upon this *"[List of non- Member States, entities and organizations having received a standing invitation to participate as observers in the sessions and the work of the General Assembly](http://www.un.org/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=A/INF/71/5)"*

What are the requirements for an entity to be granted such status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no exact criteria or process to be granted observer status. An entity just needs to have ["received a standing invitation to participate as observers"](http://www.un.org/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=A/INF/71/5).

> The present document contains the list in alphabetical order of **non-Member States, entities and organizations having received a standing invitation to participate as observers** in the sessions and the work of the General Assembly.
>
> (*emphasis mine*)

As quoted [from The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/palestinianauthority/8783992/Observer-entities-observer-states-and-full-membership-at-the-UN.html):

> The United Nations **grants observer status not only to states, but also to international bodies** such as the International Criminal Court or regional organisations such as the European Union.
>
> There are **no clear procedures on how to become an observer**, and associated powers vary accordingly. As a general rule, observer entities have access to most meetings and relevant documentation, but are not allowed to vote.
>
> (*emphasis mine*)

Observer status can be granted through a UN resolution which [was the case for Palestine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_resolution_67/19).

Similarly, there's also no exact process for granting entities *permanent* observer status as seen from [this UN FAQ](http://ask.un.org/faq/14519) and it's considered on a case-by-case basis by the General Assembly:

> The **United Nations General Assembly may grant non-member states, international organizations and other entities** Permanent Observer Status.
>
> The UN Charter and the General Assembly Rules of Procedure have **no provisions related to granting permanent observer status**.
>
> The process is described in a legal opinion of 15 August 2008, published in the 2008 United Nations Juridical Yearbook, p. 438 (in English), part B, paragraphs 8-11.
>
> Permanent Observers may participate in the sessions and workings of the General Assembly and maintain missions at the UN Headquarters.
>
> (*emphasis mine*)